# show all blogs with comments which are approved in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

there are two tables , blog and comments table. in blog table all blogs are stored an

**Blog Table**

```
----------------------------------------
id  | blog_name | date  
----------------------------------------
1   |  abc   |   31/3/17  
----------------------------------------
2   |  xyz   |   31/3/17  
----------------------------------------
3   |  rbc   |   31/3/17  
----------------------------------------
4   |  ert   |   31/3/17 
----------------------------------------
```

**Comment Table**

```
----------------------------------------
id  | comment |  blog_id | approved 
----------------------------------------
1    | abc    |    1     |     0
----------------------------------------
2    | xyz    |    1     |     1
----------------------------------------
3    | rbc    |    2     |     0
----------------------------------------
4    | ert    |    4     |     1
----------------------------------------
```

now i want to show results the  way .. that all blogs will show but with the count of comments with each blog.. but the comment count should be only for approved comments.. by default the approved comment is 0 means not approved but 1 means approved..the problem is if i join the two tables in where condition i write approved=1 then it shows only 2 blogs but i need to show all blogs with comments.. if any blog comment is not present in the comment table then it will show 0 count to me... please help me with this

im using this join.. this join not showing all blogs..

SELECT b.id,b.blog_name,COUNT(c.comment) as comment_count FROM blog b LEFT JOIN comment c ON b.id=c.blog_id WHERE c.approved=1 GROUP BY b.id

i want all blogs with comments.. it shows only approved comments related blogs..

Comment: So you want someone to write code for you?

Comment: if it will be possible with mysql query then please tell me the query how to write it.. thanks @Mayank Pandeyz

Comment: i think it is possible with nested loop i don't know how to write it..

Comment: Here is link to documentation about running queries in Codeigniter:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT 
blog.*,
COALESCE(COUNT(comments.id),0) AS comment_count

FROM blog
LEFT JOIN comments
ON comments.blog_id = blog.id AND comments.approved = 1

GROUP BY blog.id